# Inheritance Hierarchy and adding elements to a vector

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following problem. I have an abstract class with a virtual function.

```
class A{
public:
    virtual double GetTotalPrice() = 0;
```

};

A derived class:

```
class B : public A {
A (string st, int number, double num) : x(st), y(number), z(num) {  }
double GetTotalPrice()  //returns a quantity                              
{
  ...

}  };
```

A derived class from the derived class :

```
class C : public B {
C (double d, int i) : dd(d), ii(i) {} 
double GetTotalPrice()  //returns a quantity                              
{
  ...

}  };
```

My task is to create a vector with pointers to class A instances and add 3 elements of class B and 3 elements of class C to it.

Here is how I create the vector:

```
vector<A*> it;
```

But I am not sure how to add items to it, especially of class C. 
Can somebody help me with that? 
I also need to call the virtual function `GetTotalPrice()` to all of those elements. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>("string",1,1.2));//Write B's ctor arguments
vec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<C>(1.2,1));//Write C's ctor arguments
```

Using raw pointers, which is **not** recommended:

```
std::vector<A*> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new B("string",1,1.2));
vec.emplace_back(new C(1.2,1));
```

Iterating over the vector is simple and same for both variants:

```
for(auto&& e:vec)
{
    double price = e->GetTotalPrice();
}
```